# Is there any way to watch Hulu (or Hulu Plus) on the new Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, airplay, hulu

I was hoping Airplay might do this, but when I turn it on in the Hulu Plus app, it only streams the audio to the ATV.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it seems that AirPlay is [audio only](http://daringfireball.net/2010/11/airplay_limits) for third-party apps for the time being, and there's no other way to get Hulu Plus on the Apple TV.

Answer (score 1):

When AirPlay support for Safari is added (supposedly in 2011 - see below), you may be able to do this.

http://www.macrumors.com/2010/11/30/steve-jobs-airplay-video-streaming-coming-to-safari-and-third-party-apps-in-2011/

Comment: You still couldn't play Hulu, unless Hulu incorporates this into their app.